Upgrading to Python 3.10, different users - python3 alias points to same binary but shows different versions
In Debian 11 based docker container, I'm a bit confused as to why root and jenkins users' python3 command is pointing to the same binary but have different versions:
sh-5.1$ whoami
jenkins
sh-5.1$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
sh-5.1$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
sh-5.1$ 
exit
root@c5891e24911a:/home/jenkins# 
root@c5891e24911a:/home/jenkins# whoami
root
root@c5891e24911a:/home/jenkins# which python3 
/usr/bin/python3
root@c5891e24911a:/home/jenkins# python3 --version
Python 3.8.16

I tried changing version in .bachrc to 3.10 but I guess it wouldn't work because that's for non-login shells:

How can I make jenkins user's python3 command  to point to version 3.10 permanently?

which doesn't know anything about aliases (it's an external executable, not part of bash, so it can't see into shell internals). Use type python3 to see what's actually in use. (Also, note that aliases are only honored by default in interactive shells; during shell script execution -- which is more on-topic here than interactive use is -- aliases have no effect).

...so in general, the Right Way to prioritize /usr/local/bin over /usr/bin is just to modify PATH to put /usr/local/bin first. Don't use aliases -- forget they ever existed; there are almost no cases where an alias is a better choice than a shell function.

Troubleshoot

Check for alias type python :it maybe an alias pointing to another version. Check your shell config file ~/.bashrc.
Try pyenv versions if you have it installed. If not, try it for it is a great way to manage multiple versions. Set defaults and have project specific environments with different versions.

Solution
If none of the above work, ensure you have python 3.10 installed and do this:

echo 'alias python3=python3.10' >> ~jenkins/.bashrc
source ~jenkins/.bashrc
Check with su jenkins python3 --version


Boo, hiss: Jenkins is a CI system. CI jobs are run with noninteractive shells, so they ignore aliases completely. Instructing the OP to set up aliases for Jenkins is thus not something that's going to help when Jenkins is actually running a job.
